# Assigning multiple columns' value to a single variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have MySQL database with a "search_tags" filled like so:

```html
mysql> SELECT * FROM search_tags;
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | tag        | tag_group | tag_weight |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Homer      | HomeR     | 0          |
|  2 | HomeR      | HomeR     | 0          |
|  3 | HomeRU     | HomeR     | 0          |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also have a textarea for users to input their requests into. I want to parse each word using onkeyup and highlight specific tags to act as a cue for user. We use fairly obscure software and users often misspell names and modules, so autocorrecting would be a great idea, which I got working with [jQuery Auto-Correct plugin](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-auto-correct) and < span > tags. It's working great, however, list of corrections needs to be either in < script > part or in .js file in order to work. How do I fetch data from two columns (specifically tag and tag_group) in the above table and make a list out of them like so?

```
$("#textbox2").autocorrect({
    corrections: {
        arent: "aren't",
        aboutit: "about it"
        tag: "tag_group"
        tag: "tag_group"

    }
});
```

Can someone please point me to the right source or direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want `tag` and  `tag_group` values inside autocorrect?

Comment: Yes, I want the list to be in tag: "tag_group" format

Comment: are you getting this via some backend (ajax) ? If yes, show that code , both front-end and backend.